# slide from left to right gets stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I have some strange problem with Multi page slide. When I press to switch pages, new page was stuck on left and then slide out ,where it needs to be. You can test this in my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/yzf0yhq7/)

There is my JQuery. (Im new on that)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.page-content div.page").hide();
$(".page-content div.page:first-child").show();

$("a.edit").click(function() {  // EDIT BUTTON
    $("div.page-content .page").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
    var effect = 'slide';var options = { direction: 'right'};var duration = 1000;
    $(activeTab).toggle(effect, options, duration);
});

$("a.back").click(function() {  // BACK BUTTON
    $("div.page-content .page").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
    var effect = 'slide';var options = { direction: 'left'};var duration = 1000;
    $(activeTab).toggle(effect, options, duration);
});

});
```

Any solutions, why I have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slide the current page out when hiding with the toggle of activetab slide to make it a smooth run. Use the following js code and see if that makes the effect you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.page-content div.page").hide();
$(".page-content div.page:first-child").show();

  $("a.edit").click(function() {    // EDIT BUTTON
    $("div.page-content .page").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    $($(this).attr("href")).delay(1000).toggle('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000);
  });

  $("a.back").click(function() {    // BACK BUTTON
     $("div.page-content .page").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
     $($(this).attr("href")).delay(1000).toggle('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.